# Enabled LDO based on the input voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I need to power a microcontroller (ATTINY826-SU) from a USBC port that supports Power Delivery (I'll use a battery back for that). For the sake of simplicity I'll omit the circuite to negotiate the Voltage and the Current according to the Power Delivery protocol, let's simply assume that VBUS could range from 5 to 20V.

If the selected input voltage is 5V I can feed the microcontroller directly without using the LDO, on the contrary, if the voltage is greater that 5V I must use an LDO to stepdown the voltage.

In order to achieve this I've used a comparator (based on the LM393DT OPAMP). The comparator's output is connected to the base of a [P-Channel MOSFET](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_TECH-PUBLIC-TPNTS4101PT1G_C970018.html#:%7E:text=Datasheet-,TECH%20PUBLIC%20TPNTS4101PT1G,-EasyEDA) to enable/disable the LDO. Can you please suggest a way to feed the micro-controller VDD with VBUS only if its value is 5V? Can I use an NPN transistor on the high side switch configuration?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run the microcontroller on like 4.5V or 4.75V?  If you could do that then just use the LDO all the time.  There are plenty of LDOs that have dropout voltages of only a few hundred mV (or even less for low currents).  There are LDOs that have supply currents of only a few microamps if low power is also a concern.

Comment: Terminology technicality: a 7805 is most definitely *not* a LDO (**L**ow **D**rop**O**ut) regulator. It's a *Linear* regulator, and "LDO" is not an abbreviation or synonym for "Linear".

Comment: Why would you select the voltage any higher than you need? I suspect there is something more to this question...Some other part of the design can request higher voltage without your permission, right?

Comment: @brhans you're right and I appreciate the suggestion. I searched for an LDO in lcsc.com but with this acronym they mean Linear Voltage Regulator, I've replaced the 7805 with WL9100S3-50B

Comment: @Ale..chenski exactly, I've answered to you comment in the post below. Do you have any suggestion to give? Many thanks

Comment: A generic suggestion would be to begin with finding a right switching converter with wide input range (6-24V) to 5V and low standby consumption, and definitely forget the word "LDO". Then you need to design a control circuit that disables the switcher and simultaneously bypasses it with a FET switch, and do the switch gracefully without power glitches and crowbars. You may want to examine PMIC (power management IC) portfolio of TI, Analog Devices, Diodes, Linear Technology, etc., maybe they already have what you want. But the 100: 200 Ohm divider definitely does not help to save power...

Answer (score 0):

Answer edited because I originally misread the question.

So you want to negotiate USB-PD voltage to suit the current pulled by your load (for example, a 12V pump). You also need 5V for your MCU, even if the USB-PD voltage is 5V. It runs from a powerbank, so current draw should be low.

The schematic in the question has constantly-on a LM393 (0.8-1mA supply current) and LM4040 (<100µA) so we should try to use less current than this. I'm ignoring the up to 60mA drawn by the voltage divider resistors because these could easily be changed.

If your only load on 5V is the Attiny and a few low current sensors, then a simple way would be to use a LDO with low idle current and a PMOS pass transistor.

When input voltage is higher than 5V it will regulate it down to 5V, and when input voltage is 5V the LDO will operate in dropout with the internal PMOS fully turned on. In this case dropout depends on the RdsON of the internal PMOS and output current.

As an example let's look at [AP7375](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/AP7375-50Y-13?qs=rQFj71Wb1eXYUkoMPbsPQw%3D%3D) LDO: it has an idle current of 2µA which means having it on continuously isn't a problem. Datasheet says:

VDROP = 35mV@IOUT = 10mA (Typ.)
VDROP = 350mV@ IOUT = 100mA (Typ.)

So with your Attiny using 10mA, the dropout would be tiny and it would get almost 5V. Besides, Attiny works fine down to 1.8V, it will run fine on 4.965V too.

[image]

It's important to use a PMOS LDO and not a PNP, as the latter will draw current to saturate the pass transistor when operating at low input voltage.

If you have other loads on 5V that use more current, then it would be more efficient to use a switching regulator.

LDO advantages: simplicity, cost, no switching noise, low idle current

Switcher advantages: much higher efficiency at high current

For a few mA current, from a big powerbank, a switcher isn't really needed. For a few tens to hundreds of mA, then definitely yes.

In this case you need a buck chip that can operate at 98-100% duty cycle, so when the input is 5V, it will output 4.9-something volts, and when output is higher it will regulate. Here are two examples: [AP63205](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP63200-AP63201-AP63203-AP63205.pdf) [TPS54202](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/TPS54202DDCR?qs=uP22XH7NdCsJtN%2Fq54jCtQ%3D%3D).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I need to preserve the power consumption because the USBC is fed by a battery pack. In your scenario the LDO is always powered on, I would like to switch it on only if needed.

Comment: If you care about conserving battery power then a linear regulator is not what you should be using.

Comment: OK, I misread the question lol. Yes the answer is to use a switching converter that allows 100% duty cycle so it will output almost 5V on a 5V input.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max20075d-max25276d.pdf https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54202.pdf

Comment: Since the circuit allegedly uses PD to control the input voltage, the correct answer should be to always negotiate the default 5V contract and forget about downconverting. The entire purpose of PD is exactly that.

Comment: @Ale..chenski there is a reason why I would like to negotiate more than 5V. Most of my project requires 12V (for example to switch on a pump). I think that negotiating the higher voltage and than downstep it to 5V to power the microcontroller is the best approach.

Comment: @bobflux thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know that such device exists. I saw that it is quite expensive (it costs more than 4$). Do you have any other suggestions that is cheaper? Can I use an NPN transistor where the base is controlled by the comparator's output, the collector is connected to VBUS and its emitter is connected to the microcontroller? Thanks

Comment: @Angel0ne, fine, but could you outline a use case when you need to drop PD voltage to 5V (and save power by bypassing the voltage regulator)? Do you want to use 12V sporadically and negotiate the supply voltage dynamically over PD?

Comment: @Ale..chenski This circuite is generic and can be used when I need to power a load that requires 12V or even higher voltage. For example I need to build a watering system where the pump runs at 12V. The microcontroller switch it on and off periodically (e.g 15min ON, 30min OFF)

Comment: @bobflux, the LM66200 is wrong IC for the job, it switches automatically for higher input voltage, while in OP case both voltages need to be at 5V. But the idea to use ideal diode controllers is about right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151703/discussion-between-angel0ne-and-ale-chenski).